# AWS RestAPI does not forward Cognito Auth Information to Lambda function

Tags: rust, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk, aws-rest-api

as the title already implies my RestAPI does not forward the user information of the authorized client to my lambda function. I tried with a rust lambda function (see the issue [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-rust-runtime/issues/592)), but it turned out, a nodejs implementation has the same problem. I have posted my cdk setup in the above issue and i bet there is a configuration mistake i made, but just cannot find.

I checked that you need to be authroized in the first place (which works, as the gateway returns "unauthorized" in that case). But whatever i tried so far, the context.identity field is always empty/null.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user identity in the above mentioned use case can be found in the request_context, not lambda_context.

```
match request.request_context() {
    RequestContext::ApiGatewayV1(context) => {
        println!("{:?}", context.identity);
    }
}
```